# Cross Domain JavaScript, issue with parent.window.location.hash on chrome and safari

Tags: javascript

I am working on Cross Domain JavaScript technique called "Fragment Id Messaging".

M using parent.window.location.hash for attaching "#" to window location from inside iframe.
This is working fine with firefox but not working on chrome and safari.

any idea? solution?

Answer (score 0):

Safari will throw an error if you attempt to change a parent frame's location. I'm guessing that Chrome does the same. Most likely for security reasons.

Take a look at this page: http://tagneto.blogspot.com/2008/01/browser-and-dojo-updates-on-fragment-id.html